# Pop up based search and return values to parent form or any other altrenative

Tags: .net, asp.net, jquery

I have a scenario where i want user to open a popup or other page from a web form to search contacts from database and add them to list and when done return that list back to parent form field and continue filling other fields.

I have 2-3 user input which should take multiple values for each field from list of values and i wanted to implement this using pop up based search and add method (other alternative was to use dropdown with checkbox but the list is so big and it is not user friendly to use that)

Is this feasible using asp.net or is there a better architecture/method in .NET to implement this type other than popup based search and retrieval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET and jQuery are perfectly acceptable for this.  Add the required js references to your page (or master page) and jQuery works a treat.

Check out the jQuery site for the dialog component (click on the modal form example).

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

You can use javascript to modify/add to the page that's already on the client.

You can also use jQuery to do send infos back to your site, via GET or POST.  JSON is supported as well.  If you bring the MVC framework into the mix you get a bunch of other goodies that make it real easy to work with sending data back-and-forth from your controllers to the web UI.

Cheers,
-jc

Comment: thanks ... problem with using mvc is that my development is restricted to .net 2.0 web forms and my modal form should be able to do database query to get data for search terms is that possible in jquery modal form

Comment: absolutely, MVC just makes the honey taste sweeter.

it's not a modal 'form' so much as a modal 'div', so you can pre-populate it with the selection criteria, or load it dynamically.  to fetch some kind of result into a div on the page (to show the user who they selected) you simply write a $("#elementName").load(url) statement (where url is your script that generates a result).  .load also takes parameters, so if you need to pass something in via POST you can do that too.